# Multi-threading and raw input problems python

Tags: python, multithreading

so you run this it will Prompt the user for their passcode so you can type the 4 digit pin and it will print out the name and add it to the list.

```
import time
import datetime
import threading
from threading import Thread

StudentInfo={
1126:'Abel',
1134:'Diego',
}

flag = True

number=StudentInfo.keys()
name=StudentInfo.values()
StudentPresent=[]

def func1():
    global flag
    global StudentPresent
    while flag == True:
        StudentID = int(raw_input("What student are you? "))
        if StudentID in number:
            here = StudentInfo.get(StudentID)
            print here
            StudentPresent.append(here)
            print StudentPresent       
        else:
            print "Not in our system, check with Admin"
        if StudentID == 9999:
            flag= False
            print flag


#if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Thread(target = func1).start()
```

Now once I take the comment tags off the last two lines then it just runs though the function and does not allow the user to type in their number.  I took off the second threaded function because it works just fine.  It just sends an email at a designated time.  So for the purpose of the question i took all that out because this is the root of all my problems.

```
import time
import datetime
import threading
from threading import Thread

StudentInfo={
1126:'Abel',
1134:'Diego',
}

flag = True

number=StudentInfo.keys()
name=StudentInfo.values()
StudentPresent=[]

def func1():
    global flag
    global StudentPresent
    while flag == True:
        StudentID = int(raw_input("What student are you? "))
        if StudentID in number:
            here = StudentInfo.get(StudentID)
            print here
            StudentPresent.append(here)
            print StudentPresent       
        else:
            print "Not in our system, check with Admin"
        if StudentID == 9999:
            flag= False
            print flag


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to have a thread waiting for input. Threads are just supposed to go and do stuff on their own.

Comment: Thanks @KeefBaker  do you have any ideas how I could have this function run while at the same time having a system send emails out at a designated time every day.  The email portion I have works in threading but it's the input portion that messes us.  Do you have any ideas I could try to have them run at the same time?

Comment: Sorry I figured it out with your help.  Leave the user input out of the thread and simply run the thread with just the email function.  This way the thread runs in the background the whole time and then I just have to start the func1()  after I hit run.  Then it works and does not error out.  Thanks again @KeefBaker

Comment: Could you write your answer as an answer and mark it as solved?

Comment: Sorry, just seen this now. Glad you got it working. That's what I would have suggested.